# Computer still unresponsive after replacing almost all the parts

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

At some point, my computer started showing a blue screen.
Next, it didn't boot up properly anymore and got stuck in the booting phase.
At the same time, the computer started showing a red stripe diagonally on the monitor.

First, we thought it was a motherboard issue so we swapped the motherboard and CPU out for new ones.
This did solve the booting up problems.
Since we had the red stripe still in the screen, we swapped the GPU.
This looked very promising, because the stripe was now also gone.
**However**, after running the PC for two minutes and rebooting it, it would not start again at all.
Given the fact that almost everything was replaced, we figured that it must by a faulty power supply.
Alas, replacing the power supply didn't work.
We have discovered that disconnecting and reconnecting the power supply cable for the motherboard allows the fans to spin for 1/2 seconds.
After that, the PC goes silent again.

So, currently, we have a system consisting of almost only consisting of brand new parts, but still it won't start. What could it be? What might we have done wrong?

**Old hardware**

```
MoBo: Asrock b57 pro3-m
CPU: Intel core i5 760
GPU: MSI radeon r9 270x
Powersupply: unknown
RAM: Adata 2x4GB
```

**New hardware**

```
MoBo: Asrock B450M pro 4
CPU: AMD ryzen 5 1600
GPU: Geforce GT 1030
Powersupply: MSI A650GF
RAM: HyperX predator 2400 2x8GB
```

Comment: Try a basic operating system on a spare drive and see if you get the same result.

Comment: did you replace the power supply? really dirty power has caused issues like this in my experience (albeit only the once). I mean after everything else, you almost have to believe its where the computer is, rather than what parts its composed of. I know, weird.

Comment: @John could that be the problem even though the computer doesn't get past BIOS?

Comment: @FrankThomas, yes we installed a brand new power supply

Comment: I am not sure, but if  you can try it, BIOS upgrade might work.

Comment: @John Is it possible to update the BIOS while not being able to even get into BIOS settings?

Comment: It may not be - I am not sure. Possibly have a USB boot key. I am not certain.